# how to get data from a http request with firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, httprequest

I create a firebase function, in the cloud the stuff exists, in the code i return this stuff but wehen i try get the data in a http request don't charge anything.
This is my Function in firebase functions:

```js
exports.autentifyuser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var stuff = [];
    var db = admin.firestore();
    const key=req.query.ids;

    db.collection("/usuariosdinny/").where("key","==",key).get().then(snapshot => {

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var newelement = {
                "id": doc.id,
                "nombre": doc.data().nombre,
                "foto": doc.data().foto,
                "descripcion":doc.data().descripcion,
                "edad":doc.data().edad,
                "key":doc.data().key,
                "sexo":doc.data().sexo,
                "telefono":doc.data().telefono,
                "tipo":doc.data().tipo
            }
            stuff = stuff.concat(newelement);
        });
        console.log(stuff);
        res.send(stuff);
        return stuff;
    }).catch(reason => {
        res.send(reason);

        console.log(reason);
        return reason;
    })
});
```

this is the call:

```js
let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  params.set('ids',this.ids);
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
  requestOptions.search = params;
  this.http.get('https://us-central1-dinnyud-9b9c8.cloudfunctions.net/autentifyuser',requestOptions).toPromise().then(response=>console.log(response.json()) && this.navCtrl.push(TabsControllerPage) && loader.dismiss())
  .catch(error=>alert2.present()&& loader.dismiss());
```

I need the `response.json()` and get the "Tipo" data. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the call to get data from the database happens asynchronously, you need to tell Cloud Functions that you're not done yet. Otherwise it may terminate your function as soon as the last `}` has executed, which is well before the data is retrieved from Firestore.

To tell Cloud Functions about this, you have to return a promise. Luckily this is quite easy, since `get` already returns a promise.

```
return db.collection("/usuariosdinny/").where("key","==",key).get().then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
```

Comment: this is now implemented, but i need charge the data this.http.get('https://us-central1-dinnyud-9b9c8.cloudfunctions.net/autentifyuser',requestOptions).toPromise().then(response=>console.log(response.json()) && this.navCtrl.push(TabsControllerPage) && loader.dismiss())
  .catch(error=>alert2.present()&& loader.dismiss());